# Python IDLE: Tabbing Between Windows

Tags: python, python-idle

Is there a way to cycle through the open windows in Python's IDLE? It seems like the only way to do this is either go to the menu bar, or to click on the window you want. Thanks.

Comment: Does `Alt-Tab` work? Or do you want to cycle ONLY through IDLE?

Comment: @RocketDonkey - Only through IDLE. Thanks!

Comment: @RocketDonkey - Using Mac OSX.

Comment: Does Alt+` work? In case that didn't get escaped properly, that is Alt+ the key above the tab (backtick). I know nothing about OSX so that could be totally off!

Comment: @RocketDonkey - Unfortunately, no. But thanks! Out of curiosity, what's the shortcut for Windows?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant the Apple key (completely stealing from http://www.techiecorner.com/230/how-to-switch-window-within-the-same-program-in-mac-os-x/). Ha, I actually don't the Windows shortcut (although I'd like to). It seems like you can hold Ctrl and click on the tab in the toolbar (Windows 7), but that isn't as satisfying as a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @RocketDonkey - Gotcha. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for IDLE.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Well I'm sure somebody here will think of something (I'll keep an eye out as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X, if you are using an IDLE from a Python linked with an Aqua Cocoa Tcl/Tk 8.5, then the standard keyboard shortcut `Command` + ` (backtick on US keyboards) cycles through the application's open windows.  Those would include recent 64-bit/32-bit Pythons (2.7.x, 3.2.x, and 3.3.x) downloaded from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) (and, as noted there, you should install `ActiveTcl` if possible due to instabilities with the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5 in recent OS X releases.)  The 32-bit-only Pythons for older versions of OS X link with Tcl/Tk 8.4 which does not support this.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I downloaded/installed v 8.5.12, but still can't cycle through the windows. I don't completely understand what tcl/tk does; is there some setting I need to enable? Do I need to log into IDLE in a different fashion?

Comment: Tk is a GUI toolkit. Python provides a wrapper interface to Tk via the Tkinter module. IDLE uses Tkinter. Downloading and installing ActiveTcl will only help if you are using a Python (and IDLE) that was built to link with it. For example, the Apple-supplied Pythons in OS X will not use ActiveTcl. What Python version information is given in the IDLE shell window? Also, to be clearer, the keyboard shortcut with the US input method is the simultaneous pressing of the Command key and the back tick key (usually next to the 1 key).

Comment: Figured it out. I was still using v. 2.6. I installed 2.7.3, and it works now.